# I found this in my refrigerator water filter. Is it a biofilm? Is it a sign of dangerous bacteria?

Tags: species-identification, bacteriology

[image: debris from refrigerator water supply]
When I dispense water form my refrigerator after changing my filter, the following slimy tube like deposits appeared. Does anybody know what this is? Could it be a biofilm growing in the water hose, and if so, is this type of bacteria likely dangerous or benign?

Comment: The most dangerous bacteria are those that release toxins, and those that can reproduce very happily at 37 degrees inside the human body. lower temperature bacteria are not typically the most competitive at 37 degrees. you;d need to search reagents that identify biological molecules, lipids, proteins, carbs, amd run some test to identify it..  Biofilms develop with a good supply of micronutrients and nitrogen.